# Fix the bin locations of stat_summary_hex

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm plotting data on a map which was obtained from two different sources. I want to plot these side-by-side (using `facet_wrap`) so the sourced can be easily compared to one another, and I'm using the ggplot function `stat_summary_hex` to create hexbins.

If my data frame `df` contains the four variables `lon`, `lat`, `score` and `source`, my code might look like this:

```
world_map <- map_data('world')

ggplot(df) + aes(x = lon, y = lat, z = score) +
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(-5, 10), ylim = c(45, 60)) +
  stat_summary_hex(binwidth = c(.7, .5), fun = median) +
  geom_map(dat = world_map, map = world_map, inherit.aes = FALSE,
           mapping = aes(map_id = region), fill = 'white', color = 'black') +
  facet_wrap( ~ source, ncol = 2) +
  theme(legend.position = 'top') + labs(x = '', y = '')
```

The problem I'm experiencing is that the bins are generated for the left and right plot separately, and because the data has different ranges, the bins do not line up. This makes it more difficult to compare the plots. Is there any way I can force the bins to line up?

I know that in `geom_histogram` I could set the `center` or `boundary` parameters. There is no such parameter in `stat_summary_hex`, so maybe I could fiddle with the data ranges or something? I'm using `coord_cartesian`, so maybe I can add a "fake" data point outside of my plotted area to force the bins into a certain position?

I would share a data example, but I can't share the data I'm actually using. I could create some fake data but I think (hope) the question is understandable without.

Here is the plot:

[image: plot]

(Don't get too distracted by the colours - a normal summary function would return a continuous scale, but I'm using a custom one to return a discrete one.)

Comment: what if you take the data points of your right source as empty data points into the left source. I am thinking on something like "white hex bins" as placeholder.